# Reading Sql Database from backward

Tags: java, android, sql, database, cursor

Hey guy I have a question. How can I read my Sql datas from backward. I tried a lot of things I found in the net but nothing works here is my code:

```
public Cursor getAllRows() {
    String where = null;
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, 
                        where, null, null, null,null,null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
```

And the code for the Cursor:

```
Cursor cursor = myDb.getAllRows();

// Allow activity to manage lifetime of the cursor.
// DEPRECATED! Runs on the UI thread, OK for small/short queries.
startManagingCursor(cursor);

// Setup mapping from cursor to view fields:
String[] fromFieldNames = new String[] 
        {DBAdapter.KEY_KALO, DBAdapter.KEY_HYDRATE, DBAdapter.KEY_FAT, DBAdapter.KEY_PROTEIN ,DBAdapter.KEY_CAL};
int[] toViewIDs = new int[]
        {R.id.item_Kalorien,     R.id.item_KG_in_g,           R.id.item_F_in_g,     R.id.item_P_in_g,R.id.item_cal};

// Create adapter to may columns of the DB onto elemesnt in the UI.
SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter = 
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this,       // Context
                R.layout.item_tagebuch, // Row layout template
                cursor,                 // cursor (set of DB records to map)
                fromFieldNames,         // DB Column names
                toViewIDs               // View IDs to put information in
                );

// Set the adapter for the list view
ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
```

Tank you for helping, and sorry for my bad english:)

Comment: `read my Sql datas from backward` doesn't mean a lot to me... did you mean `how do I show data in a reverse order`?

Comment: yes:) sorry I dont know how to say it

Comment: `cursor.moveToLast();` `while(cursor.hasPrevious()) { // do your code }`

Comment: OK, so make your **rawQuery** look like `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myField = someValue ORDER BY someOtherField DESC` (DESC means DESCending order, while the default is ASCending)

Comment: hmm what is has.Previous for a command?

Comment: and where should I add this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement "from backward" is ambiguous i am assuming you want to read db in a particular order

if you want to read in descending  order of a field say 'foo' then

`String ORDER = "foo DESC";/*use ASC for ascending  order*/`

and Change the cod as follows

```
public Cursor getAllRows() {
    String where = null;
    String Order = "foo DESC";
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, 
                        where, null, null, null,Order,null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
```

Here is the syntax of query

`public Cursor query (String table, String[] columns, String selection,String[]`
`selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy, String limit)`

Refer to the below link for further explanantion
[SQLiteDatabase Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Can you let me know what the exception is ?
Instead of checking if c != null Check if c.getCount() is 0 or not ,
The query will anyway return a cursor object so it wont be null anywayz

Comment: 06-26 08:32:54.433: E/SQLiteLog(979): (1) no such column: foo

Comment: 06-26 08:35:01.203: E/AndroidRuntime(1338): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{food.manager/food.manager.VerlaufEssen}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: foo (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT DISTINCT _id, kalo, hydate, fat, protein, cal FROM mainTable ORDER BY foo DESC

Comment: here your Exception:)

Comment: Thankss ahh I changed foo haha sorry;)

Comment: Hi don't use the name foo as it is use any field name with which you want to order foo should be replaced with the column name which you want in reverse order

Answer (score 0):

By backwards is kind of a strange word but I presume you need to sort the data so here is something

**1.** Sort before getting the data

This can be done using the **ORDER BY** keyword. The last parameter in db.query() method is the order by clause (without the "order by" keyword).

So change your query as

```
Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, 
                    where, null, null, null,null,COLUMN_NAME + " ASC");
```

ASC is for sorting by Ascending and DESC for decending

and if you want more than one sort then do it like this

```
Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, 
                    where, null, null, null,null,COLUMN_NAME + " ASC, " +COLUMN_NAME2 + " DESC");
```

**2.** Sorting after getting the data

If your trying to sort it after getting the data then it should be done at cursor level

```
Cursor cursor = myDb.getAllRows();
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
    // do what you need with the cursor here
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

OR REVERSE

```
if (cursor.moveToLast()) {
    do {
    // do what you need with the cursor here
    } while (cursor.moveToPrevious());
}
```

Comment: Hmm.I got a runtime Exception..:(

Comment: hmm and if I do the second way there is no runtime Exception but it doesnt work:( hmm

Comment: hmm should i change my GetAllRow method in the second example too? @Girish Nair